# ng-repeat filter is not working for repeat variable assignments

Tags: angularjs

This [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alaksandarjesus/vq1wdg84/) will give better information on the code.

The selected item  should filter other value and i shall have a button outside the list item what will reassign the selected value to null so all list items are displayed.

Clicking on the radio button it should hide the other elements.

**CONTROLLER**

```
var myApp = angular.module("repeat",["ngSanitize"]);

myApp.controller("repeatController", function($sce, $window, $scope){

$scope.test ="Controller is working fine";

$scope.lists=[{"name":"asdf","desc":"dummy text 1"},{"name":"wee","desc":"dummy text 2"},{"name":"fgs","desc":"dummy text 3"}]


});
```

**HTML**

```
<li ng-repeat ="list in lists | filter:{name:selected}">
    <label ng-click="selected = list.name">
        <input type="radio">
        {{list.name}}{{selected}}
    </label>

</li>
```

Comment: I cannot understand the problem, do you mean the radios remain all checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understood what you need [here is the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/0ea79Ln3/1) to hide the radio button not clicked:

HTML:

```
<div  ng-app="repeat" ng-controller="repeatController">
    <li ng-repeat ="list in lists" ng-hide="selected !== undefined && selected !== list.name">
        <label ng-click="$parent.selected = list.name">
            <input type="radio" name="selector" />
            {{list.name}}-{{selected}}
        </label>
    </li>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module("repeat", []);

myApp.controller("repeatController", function($sce, $window, $scope){

    $scope.test ="Controller is working fine";

    $scope.lists=[{"name":"asdf","desc":"dummy text 1"},{"name":"wee","desc":"dummy text 2"},{"name":"fgs","desc":"dummy text 3"}]
});
```

As suggested, you also need to remove the ngSanitize from the Fiddle or add it as file too (for example adding this resource but for the purpose of the fiddle you don't need it https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.min.js)

Comment: Its working as expected. The question is why should i use $parent, if i dont have child ng-repeat.....

Comment: Because `ng-repeat` creates a new scope for each iteration so you need to use `$parent` in this case. Yes you can use filter or hide, there are many ways to do that. Instead using the $parent you can also use a function like `sel(list.name)`and in the controller `$scope.sel = function (name) { $scope.selected = name; }`

Comment: In such case, if i use $parent in filter as filter:{name:$parent.selected}, its not working. i load ngSanitize in my project. So no issues with ngSanitize.

Answer (score 0):

You have the problem with `ngSanitize`, Please remove the `ngSanitize` in your module then it's working good.

Your module should be like this below code

```
var myApp = angular.module("repeat",[]);
```

See this [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vq1wdg84/3/)

Comment: i load ngSanitize in my project. That's not the issue